# How to get nested value in Laravel collections

Tags: php, laravel

The collection I retrieved from database is something like:

```
$data = [
    [
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'phone' => [
            'home' => 123,
            'work' => 456,
            'cell' => 789,
        ]
    ],
    ....
];
```

Now I want to put the data into a table, so in `table.blade.php` I put something like

```
@foreach ($data as $row)
    <tr>
        @foreach ($columns as $col)
            <td>{{ $row[$col] }}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I define the `$columns` as

```
$columns = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'phone.home',  // <== I think it cannot access nested value this way, is there any way to do that?
    'phone.work',
    'phone.cell',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue, you just have to use `Arr::get` helper. It allows the use of `dot.notation` so you can do `phone.home` for example. Read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-get).

So, your code should be like this:

```
@foreach ($data as $row)
    <tr>
        @foreach ($columns as $col)
            <td>{{ Arr::get($row, $col) }}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The problem is the `$data` is actually a collection rather than an array.  And the `phone` field is from `hasMany()` relationship, so it would disappear if I use `$data->toArray()`.  Is there any better way than just creating multiple `appends` such as `getHomePhoneAttribute()`, `getWorkPhoneAttribute()`, `getCellPhoneAttribute()` etc?

Comment: You sould still be able to use the collection, no need to do do `->toArray()`. Did you try my code ?